# ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol is not SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault

Tags: c#, ssl

I am on *Windows 10 1903*, and my IE and Chrome can access Tls 1.2 website without any special settings. But when I try to use my .net 4.7.2 application to access a web API which only allows Tls 1.2 connect, my connection got terminated by the server.

I have to add `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` in my code to allow my application to connect to that endpoint correctly.

But after doing some research, I found from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol?view=netframework-4.7.2) document that for .Net 4.7 and above the default value for `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` should be `SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault` and according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-?redirectedfrom=MSDN) document the Tls 1.2 protocal is enable by default.

So I traced my code and found that the default value for `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` on my system is `System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls`. What's more crazy, when I set the protocol to `SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault`, I got this error:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : An error occurred while sending the request.
---- System.Net.WebException : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
-------- System.ArgumentException : The specified value is not valid in the 'SslProtocolType' enumeration.
Parameter name: sslProtocolType
```

I checked my system [registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/tls-registry-settings#tls-12) and IE settings, and nothing overrides or disables Tls 1.2.

So I am very confused and wonder if is there something wrong with my system or with my code.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ran into this at the office. My understanding is that the SystemDefault value comes from the Windows registry.

```
The DefaultSecureProtocols registry entry can be added in the following path:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp
On x64-based computers, DefaultSecureProtocols must also be added to the Wow6432Node path:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp
The registry value is a DWORD bitmap. The value to use is determined by adding the values corresponding to the protocols desired.

DefaultSecureProtocols Value    Protocol enabled
0x00000008  Enable SSL 2.0 by default
0x00000020  Enable SSL 3.0 by default
0x00000080  Enable TLS 1.0 by default
0x00000200  Enable TLS 1.1 by default
0x00000800  Enable TLS 1.2 by default
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi

Comment: Yes, my machine is in AD, so I think some AD configuration can affect that. But that KB is for servers. I am working on a desktop Windows 10.

Comment: The article applies to Windows servers and desktops. For our Windows 10 workstations, we had to configure the default to TLS1.2 so that some vendor software would work they way we wanted. If you don't set it explicitly, Windows 10 defaults to a lower version.

Comment: But [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-?redirectedfrom=MSDN) document says Tls 1.2 is enabled by default on Windows 10...

Comment: My understanding is that TLS1.2 is enabled in Win10 but the SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault setting can be lower the TLS1.2. I'll see if I can find the reg update we used for our issue.

Answer (score 11):

You will get this error if the app you're running *targets* a .NET framework earlier than 4.6 (even if you are actually running it on a newer .NET FX). You can check this by examining the value of `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.TargetFrameworkName`.

Specifically, this will get thrown in such a case where the [SystemDefaultTlsVersions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#systemdefaulttlsversions) registry value is not set to `1`:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/SecureProtocols/_SslState.cs,164

[AppContext switches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/appcontextswitchoverrides-element#remarks) won't help you either, as they only take effect for framework versions starting from 4.6. Assuming you can't change the targeted .NET version ([example](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1659#issuecomment-636996663)) and you don't want to force your users to change their registry settings, I recommend code like this:

```
if (ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol != SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault)
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
}
```

For more information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

Comment: You're definitely right about reason of this error (.NET Framework targeting). Author used SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault enum value, which was introduced in 4.6 only. As a result he gets SslProtocolType error indicates that SystemDefault  is not in list of available protocols.

Comment: I'm targeting 4.6.1 but I still get this error and the SecurityProtocolType enum doesn't contain a definition for SystemDefault.

Comment: @Bip901 `SystemDefault` was introduced in .NET 4.7. So if your version is lower, I guess you'll have to hard-code `Tls12`.

Comment: This was the solution for me and it was due to an httpRuntime element in the web.config still targeting .NET 4.5.2 even after I'd upgraded the project to 4.7.2 in project properties. No explicit setting of SecurityProtocol needed for me after this.

Answer (score 5):

With .NET 4.6 installed you still must put in a registry key to have .NET programs compiled for earlier versions to use strong cryptography. Once this is set, all .NET code will use the newer TLS protocols-

**64 bit**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
```

**32 bit**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
```

.NET programs compiled for 4.6 framework and higher will act as if the key is there.
The ServiceEndpointManager.SecurityProtocol setting can be used to specify it explicitly so it will be used even w/o the registry.

More info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-support-in-sharepoint-server-2019#34---enable-strong-cryptography-in-net-framework-45-or-higher

Comment: This answer directly solved a blocking problem for us. and is the only solution to enabling TLS 1.2 or higher on machines with .NET 4.6 installed

Answer (score 1):

Was this problem when debugging in Visual Studio 2015? If so, the answer is likely because you have 'Enable the Visual Studio hosting process' turned on (the default).

The vshost.exe generated by VS 2015 incorrectly has TargetFramework=4.5 set in its metadata. Even though you are running in Framework 4.7, .NET honours the TargetFramework and sets ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol to Ssl3|Tls.

Your real .exe will have the correct TargetFramework metadata. When you run it SecurityProtocol will be set to SystemDefault.

It's a bug in VS 2015 that never got fixed. You can turn off the VS hosting process in project properties. The vshost process doesn't exist in VS 2017 and later.